# One Font awesome icon not showing, despite others that do

Tags: html, css

I wanted to add a certain font awesome icon (fa-arrow-alt-circle-down), but it's not showing. I copied the classes from the website and entered them in my HTML. I tried other icons before and there was no issue with them. Sometimes I change `.far` to `.fa`, but now that doesn't work either. Can someone see why?

```
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
            <h1 class="heading-primary heading-primary--main"> Wizard's unite fans</h1>
              <div class="navigation-container">
                <button class="find-locals-nav-btn">Find Local players</button>
                <button class="forum-nav-btn">Forum</button>
                <button>login / register</button>
              </div>
              <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-down"></i>

    </div>
```

**SCSS file**

```
.jumbotron {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
  ), url("https://i.amz.mshcdn.com/-7R3bLC1xTVhrjc86pBeYAogXFY=/950x534/filters:quality(90)/https%3A%2F%2Fblueprint-api-production.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fuploads%2Fcard%2Fimage%2F760683%2F2117d274-d2cf-46b9-b60c-698d65361438.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 85vh, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 85%, 0 100%);
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  .heading-primary {
    opacity: .8;
  }

  @include respond(phone) {
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90vh, 0 100%);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 90vh, 0 100%);
    background-position: center top;
  }

  .navigation-container {
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 2rem;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 4rem auto 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1rem;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ccc, #666);

    > * {
      background-color: transparent;
      border: none;
      flex: 1 0 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #fff;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 1px;

      &:hover {
        transform: translateY(-.2rem);
      }

      &:not(:last-child) {
        border-right: 1px solid #444;
      }
    }
  }

  .fa-arrow-alt-circle-down {
    font-size: 4rem;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.fa` Font Awesome are v4. `.far` are v5.

For all icons existing in both, changing `far` to `fa` will do the trick. For the ones added in v5, obviously, it won't, as they do not exist in v4.

You can view [all v4.7 icons here](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/cheatsheet/).

For future notice, finding version specific FA icons is by searching for "font awesome x.x cheatsheet". Replace `x.x` with the proper version.

Comment: @tilly more precisely we have `far` and `fas` and the `fa` is like `far` BUT some `far` are in the PRO package so only their solid version `fas` will work . https://fontawesome.com/icons/arrow-alt-circle-down?style=regular

Comment: It depends. It's not free. It's usually embedded with either the theme or some framework. Bootstrap contains FA `v4.7`. You can replace it with `v5` but you should note only a few icon sets are free.